# Using Feeds XPath Parser to create multiple entities from a single, denormalized element

Tags: feeds

Here's an example element from my source data:

```
<relation name="parent" active="#Mom #Dad" passive="#child1 #child2" />
```

From this source, I want to create 3 different entities (relations):

```
#Mom -> #child1, #child2
#Dad -> #child1, #child2
#Mom <-> #Dad
```

The problem is the data is so terribly denormalized compared to what Feeds expects. I'm not sure whether to tap into the feeds import process using some crazy hook implementations, or whether to just build a script to reformat the data before sending it to Feeds in the first place.

Thoughts?